# I don't understand this error message (Python)

Tags: python, message

I'm just beginning Python and I wrote this small program that's supposed to take user input and print a result. However, I don't understand the error that's occuring when I run it:

**Code:**

```
# The purpose of this program is to use the user's input (the price of their meal), and outputs a receipt telling them how much the meal costs with tax and an optional tip.

print("Thank you for coming! We hoped you enjoyed the meal. Please use our all new PythonBillPayer! A fast way to pay for your day!")

PriceOfMeal = float(input("Please enter the price of your meal"))
TipAmount = float(input("Please enter amount of tip you would like to give"))

def receiptCalculation(PriceOfMeal, TipAmount):
    NewPrice = (((((13/100)*PriceOfMeal)) + PriceOfMeal) + TipAmount)
    return NewPrice

print(receiptCalculation(PriceOfMeal))
```

**Error Message:**

```
builtins.TypeError: receiptCalculation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'TipAmount'
```

Comment: Look at your function; it says it takes `PriceOfMeal` and `TipAmount`. You are calling it with just `PriceOfMeal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `receiptCalculation` need to Arguments: `PriceOfMeal` *and* `TipAmount`. `receiptCalculation(PriceOfMeal)` passes only one argument to the method, so it raises an Error.

Answer (score 0):

`receiptCalculation`
takes two arguments, yet on the line:

```
print(receiptCalculation(PriceOfMeal))
```

Only one argument is given. So the interpreter is telling you that you're missing exactly one argument in the call to your function.